# PostgreSQL comparing two timestamptz

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime

I'm doing pagination over a feed of data with a date (timestamptz) used as the cursor. The feed consists of multiple different types of posts.

One of the queries (simplified) look like this:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.title,
    EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM a.created) * 1000 AS stamp
FROM
    table a
ORDER BY
    a.created DESC
LIMIT 2
```

**Which returns:**

```
722  Hello text 1   1460040343523.98
721  Hello text 2   1460027168427.71
```

Now, (for whatever reason) I only want to get the posts earlier than id 721, I do:

```
SELECT
    a.id, a.title,
    EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM a.created) * 1000 AS stamp
FROM
    table a
WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM a.created) * 1000 > 1460027168427.71
ORDER BY
    a.created DESC
LIMIT 2
```

Note the `1460027168427.71 > 1460027168427.71`

**Result: (no difference)**

```
722  Hello text 1   1460040343523.98
721  Hello text 2   1460027168427.71
```

The comparison of the timestamps does not work, behaving like a `>=` rather like a `>`.

Note, I've tried extracting the EPOCH only, comparing the dates without any type conversion - same result. I did however note that when I got date strings of the type:

```
2016-04-07T11:06:08.427Z
```

it end up comparing

```
2016-04-07T11:06:08.427Z > 2016-04-07 11:06:08.427713+00
```

which makes me think it's a precision issue, since `427000` actually is less than `427713`.

I'm grateful for any help with this (seemingly basic) issue. And before everyone telling me to use the id's to traverse the feed - I can't, because the feed is built out of multiple different sources - with the timestamp as the common point.

Comment: Show your attempt with comparing timestamps. Also: Do you have date strings or actual timestampz?

Comment: Did you try: `a.created > to_timestamp(1460027168427)`

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but Ive just had the same problem with my feed query today:

```
# ...
WHERE post."updatedAt" > '2019-07-29 13:57:47'
```

was returning like >= too

the solution was increment one second with the date/time operator found on the docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html

The final where looks like:

```
# ...
WHERE post."updatedAt" > TIMESTAMP '2019-07-29 13:57:47' + INTERVAL '1 second'
```